# kubectl - Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, hana

I'm trying to install SAP HANA Express docker image in a Kubernete node in Google Cloud Platform as per guide https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hxe-k8s-advanced-analytics.html#7f5c99da-d511-479b-8745-caebfe996164 however, during execution of step 7 "Deploy your containers and connect to them" I'm not getting the expected result.

I'm executing command `kubectl create -f hxe.yaml` and here is the yaml file I'm using it:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-01-18T19:14:38Z
  name: hxe-pass
data:
  password.json: |+
    {"master_password" : "HXEHana1"}
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: persistent-vol-hxe
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 150Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/hxe_pv"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hxe-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hxe
  labels:
    name: hxe
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: hxe
      app: hxe
      role: master
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: hxe
        app: hxe
        role: master
        tier: backend
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: install
          image: busybox
          command: [ 'sh', '-c', 'chown 12000:79 /hana/mounts' ]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: hxe-data
              mountPath: /hana/mounts
      volumes:
        - name: hxe-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
             claimName: hxe-pvc
        - name: hxe-config
          configMap:
             name: hxe-pass
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: docker-secret
      containers:
      - name: hxe-container
        image: "store/saplabs/hanaexpress:2.00.045.00.20200121.1"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 39013
            name: port1
          - containerPort: 39015
            name: port2
          - containerPort: 39017
            name: port3
          - containerPort: 8090
            name: port4
          - containerPort: 39041
            name: port5
          - containerPort: 59013
            name: port6
        args: [ "--agree-to-sap-license", "--dont-check-system", "--passwords-url", "file:///hana/hxeconfig/password.json" ]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: hxe-data
            mountPath: /hana/mounts
          - name: hxe-config
            mountPath: /hana/hxeconfig
      - name: sqlpad-container
        image: "sqlpad/sqlpad"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hxe-connect
  labels:
    app: hxe
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 39013
    targetPort: 39013
    name: port1
  - port: 39015
    targetPort: 39015
    name: port2
  - port: 39017
    targetPort: 39017
    name: port3
  - port: 39041
    targetPort: 39041
    name: port5
  selector:
    app: hxe
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sqlpad
  labels:
    app: hxe
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    protocol: TCP
    name: sqlpad
  selector:
    app: hxe
```

I'm also using the last version of HANA Express Edition docker image: `store/saplabs/hanaexpress:2.00.045.00.20200121.1` that you can see available here: https://hub.docker.com/_/sap-hana-express-edition/plans/f2dc436a-d851-4c22-a2ba-9de07db7a9ac?tab=instructions

The error I'm getting is the following:

[image: Error: failed to start container "install": Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/data/hxe_pv': mk dir /data: read-only file system]

Any thought on what could be wrong?

Best regards and happy new year for everybody.

Comment: Similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64431454/google-kubernetes-engine-gke-cluster-error-while-creating-mount-source-path

Comment: Hello Mahboob, thanks for your suggestion. It helped me to solve my main stopper that was the node pool image being Container-Optimized. I switched this image to Ubuntu and now it is at least starting the containers and getting up the pods.

Comment: You shouldn't usually use `hostPath:` volumes, especially on a managed cloud environment.  Can you delete the explicit `PersistentVolume` and the `storageClassName:` in the `PersistentVolumeClaim`?  GKE should automatically provision a persistent volume for you.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please copy&paste text like program output or error messages into the post (as *block quotes*) instead of providing pixel raster renditions: heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the Mahboob suggestion now I can start the pods (partially) and the issue is not poppin up in the "busybox" container starting stage. The problem was that I was using an Container-Optimized image for the node pool and the required one is Ubuntu. If you are facing a similar issue double check the image flavor you are choosing at the moment of node pool creation.

However, I have now a different issue, the pods are starting (both the hanaxs and the other for sqlpad), nevertheless one of them, the sqlpad container, is crashing at some point after starting and the pod gets stuck in CrashLoopBackOff state. As you can see in picture below, the pods are in CrashLoopBackOff state and only 1/2 started and suddenly both are running.

[image: kubectl get pods command]

I'm not hitting the right spot to solve this problem since I'm a newcomer to the kubernetes and docker world. Hope some of you can bring some light to me.

Best regards.

Comment: If the issue from original question has been solved, leave your answer and create new post with new issue description.